# Applying case when date

Tags: oracle

I have to set the start date as 01-01-year which would be pulled from the expense date field. I have written the below query

```
select to_date(extract(year from rpt.expense_date),'yyyy') from rpt
```

How can I set the date to 01-01-year which would be pulled from above query.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use `TRUNC` to truncate to the start of the year:

```sql
SELECT TRUNC(expense_date, 'YY') FROM rpt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just truncate the date value:

```
trunc(rpt.expense_date, 'YYYY')
```

By default [the `trunc()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TRUNC-date.html) truncates to midnight on the specified day, equivalent to `trunc(<date>, 'DD')`, but [you can use other elements](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ROUND-and-TRUNC-Date-Functions.html#GUID-8E10AB76-21DA-490F-A389-023B648DDEF8).

---

In your code:

```
to_date(extract(year from rpt.expense_date),'yyyy')
```

you are only supplying the year element to `to_date()`; in that situation the other date elements default to the first day of the current month - so today that would give you June 1st in that year, not January 1st. That's hidden away a bit [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/nlspg/datetime-data-types-and-time-zone-support.html#GUID-4D95F6B2-8F28-458A-820D-6C05F848CA23):

> If you specify a date value without a time component, then the default time is midnight. If you specify a date value without a date, then the default date is the first day of the current month.